# Why Multilist with search is not showing data in case of data source content setup in multilingual?

Tags: content-search, multilingual, sitecore-query

We have found one issue when we add a data source to the field MULTILIST with search it works fine but in case if we add a new language version for that data source then it’s giving only first three records.

**Example** –

Data source values.

```
1  Argentina – No language version added
2. Armenia -   No language version added
3. Belgium -   No language version added
4. Brazil  -   No language version added
5. DR Congo -  No language version added
6. Ecuador -   No language version added
```

Without language versions, it’s giving correct data for the selection, below is the screen shot.
[image]

**Issue details-**

If we add a new language version for these data source values, As the example below.

```
1  Argentina –  Added 1 language version
2. Armenia –   Added 1 language version
3. Belgium–    Added 1 language version
4. Brazil –    Added 1 language version
5. DR Congo–   Added 1 language version
6. Ecuador–    Added 1 language version
```

Below is the reference screenshot where one three records are showing.
[image]

**Note:-** We have also tried with Fiddler tools just to track the request and response details, what we have observed here is-

We are getting a response from the backend but somehow it's not showing in the multi-list.

Below is the screenshot from the fiddler response.

[image]

Have anyone faced similar issue while using this control(Multilist with search) in multilingual environment, Please suggest

**Query for the datasource**

**StartSearchLocation={56EeeeF8B-272D-4B62-8930-79E1087AD7CE}&Filter=-_name:People&PageSize=210&SortField=_name[asc]**

Comment: What is your sitecore version ? Also please let us know how you have specified source of this field ?

Comment: Please share your datasource query in the Multilist with search field template

Comment: I just tried this with Sitecore 8.2 update 2 without putting any filter in datasource query but i am not able to replicate this issue.Please provide your Sitecore version and datasource query

Comment: @prabhat - Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160302)
March 02, 2016
.NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000

Comment: StartSearchLocation={56ECerwe8B-272D-4B62-8930-79E1087AD7CE}&Filter=-_name:Country&PageSize=210&SortField=_name[asc]

Comment: Working fine for me with the vanilla setup of Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160302) and the same datasource query in multilingual

Comment: let me try on a fresh installation, maybe issue within current project setup, I will share more details

Comment: I have tried with Lucene then it works but I am using Solr and it's not working

Comment: I think you may need to switch to advanced search https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/372032

Answer (score 1):

I have raised a Sitecore support ticket (Reference number is 493265),  then set up a call to describe this scenario in details, they have reviewed this item and identified as an issue and have provided a fix.

After applying this patch, it's working fine.